# Nuxt layouts not being added to routes

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

We've got a Nuxt setup with an auto-generated `router.js`. What I'm trying to achieve is a different layout for specific pages, with a different html structure. What I'm expecting to happen, is that the layout will be added to nuxt.config.js, as a meta tag (`meta: { layout: 'newLayout' }`).

What I did:

1. created the new layout file in /layouts/, `newLayout.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="testclass">
    <Top />
    <Header />
    <nuxt />
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Top from '~/components/Top.vue';
import Header from '~/components/Header.vue';
import Footer from '~/components/Footer.vue';
import init from '~/mixins/init';

export default {
  components: {
    Top,
    Header,
    Footer,
  },
  mixins: [init],
  mounted() {
    console.log('blep');
  },
};
</script>
```

2. Specified I wanted to use the new layout in the pages I need it in. I've tried both

```
   meta: {
       layout: 'newLayout',
   },
```

and just

```
    layout: 'newLayout',
```

3. I'm checking to see if anything shows up in `router.js`, but so far it doesn't. The correct layout isn't loaded either (naturally).

My file tree is as follows:

```
nuxt/
--| components/
--| layouts/
----| default.vue
----| newLayout.vue
--| pages/
----| newLayout/
------| _.vue
------| index.vue
----| _.vue
----| index.vue
----| newLayout.vue
```

Which step am I missing?

NB. I can write my own check in `nuxt.config.js`, and add the meta tag myself but this also gives unexpected results... the output is `meta: {"layout":"newLayout"},`, which doesn't seem to be correct as "layout" should be without quotes? It doesn't work either way... and if I read the docs and examples correctly, I should not have to be required to edit in the layouts information manually anyway.

Comment: from https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/, 'Nuxt.js automatically generates the vue-router configuration based on your file tree of Vue files inside the pages directory.'

Comment: That's true, I added my file tree to the question. The problem is, is that according to documentation, the newLayout should be working like this, but it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, so if anyone runs into this problem in the future, the issue in this case came from the use of nested routing in combination with the Layouts.

In the tree in my post you can see I have a /pages/newLayout/ *folder*, but also the /pages/newLayout.vue *file*, which adds the nesting to the routes for me [(documentation)](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#nested-routes). The super obvious solution is of course to specify the layout in **that** file, as the pipeline starts there, and voila it works.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <nuxt-child />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  layout: 'newLayout',
};
</script>
```